# how to draw rect over screen on OS X?

Tags: macos, cocoa, drawing, core-graphics

I want  draw rectangle over current screen on OS X like rectangle from Grab app when user select area to capture.
Could anybody give me advice about how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would do this it to, create your own custom window, you can then give it a transparent background and a border representing your selection rectangle. Do a google search for customer window Cocoa, or irregular shape window cocoa and you will find lots of examples.